# Non-standard variable name

Tags: go

Say I want to represent HTTP headers with a struct, something like:

```
   Headers struct {
     'x-requested-by' 'foo'
   }
```

it definitely does not like a variable name with hyphens, etc. Any way around this?

Comment: Specify actual header names as field tags and use those field tags when encoding or decoding the struct to the wire.

Comment: @ThunderCat can you show an example of that? will upvote thx

Comment: Or you could use a `map[string][]string` which is what `http.Header` is in the standard library.

Comment: Using a struct for headers is going to be pretty rough anyway. The set of headers you can handle will be fixed at compile-time, you'll be allocating for headers whether or not they're present, and you won't be able to iterate them. I would strongly recommend just using a map like the stdlib (and every other HTTP lib I've ever seen) does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify actual header names as field tags and use those field tags when encoding or decoding the struct to the wire. See the [encoding/json](https://godoc.org/encoding/json) package for an example of how to do this.

If the higher-level problem is storing key-value pairs with arbitrary string keys, then use a map.